# Google sheets permissions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, permissions, data-entry

In the company we have put together a series of interrelated Spreadsheets, where some work as a data entry form, and another acts as a database, where all the information entered is stored.

The data entry templates have the following code outline, made with Apps Scripts:

```
// Limpiar celdas
function Limpiar() {
  var hojaActiva = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formulario = hojaActiva.getSheetByName("Ingreso Personal");

  var celdasALimpiar = ["C3", "C4", "C5", "C6", "C7", "C8", "C11"]; // Celdas a limpiar
   for (var i=0; i<celdasALimpiar.length; i++){
     formulario.getRange(celdasALimpiar[i]).clearContent();
   }
}

// Guardar celdas
function Guardar(){
  var hojaActiva = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formulario = hojaActiva.getSheetByName("Ingreso Personal"); // Nombre de hoja del formulario
  var hojaDestino = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1CuP5yRxKrhubZbkb9KrTSJFn5OqyTPzbDi2ixKwJEpY')
  var datos = hojaDestino.getSheetByName("F09-Personal"); // Nombre de hoja donde se almacenan datos

  // Celdas de donde se obtendrán los datos a guardar
  var valores = [[formulario.getRange("C3").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("C4").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("C5").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("C6").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("C7").getValue(),
                 formulario.getRange("C8").getValue()]];

  // Inyección de datos a hoja donde se almacenan datos
  datos.getRange(datos.getLastRow()+1,1,1,6).setValues(valores); // El "6" se cambia por cantidad de datos a almacenar

  Limpiar(); // Ejecución de función para limpieza de celdas
}

// Buscar
var NUM_COLUMNA_BUSQUEDA = 0;
function Buscar() {

  var hojaActiva = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formulario = hojaActiva.getSheetByName("Ingreso Personal"); // Nombre de hoja del formulario
  var valor = formulario.getRange("C11").getValue();
  var hojaDestino = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1CuP5yRxKrhubZbkb9KrTSJFn5OqyTPzbDi2ixKwJEpY')
  var valores = hojaDestino.getSheetByName("F09-Personal").getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < valores.length; i++) {
     var fila = valores[i];
    if (fila[NUM_COLUMNA_BUSQUEDA] == valor) {
      
      formulario.getRange("C3").setValue(fila[0]);
      formulario.getRange("C4").setValue(fila[1]);
      formulario.getRange("C5").setValue(fila[2]);
      formulario.getRange("C6").setValue(fila[3]);
      formulario.getRange("C7").setValue(fila[4]);
      formulario.getRange("C8").setValue(fila[5]);
    }
  }
}

// Actualizar
function Actualizar(){
  var hojaActiva = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formulario = hojaActiva.getSheetByName("Ingreso Personal"); // Nombre de hoja del formulario
  var hojaDestino = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1CuP5yRxKrhubZbkb9KrTSJFn5OqyTPzbDi2ixKwJEpY');
  var datos = hojaDestino.getSheetByName("F09-Personal"); // Nombre de hoja donde se almacenan datos
  
  var valor = formulario.getRange("C11").getValue();
  var valores = hojaDestino.getSheetByName("F09-Personal").getDataRange().getValues(); // Nombre de hoja donde se almacenan datos
  for (var i = 0; i < valores.length; i++) {
    var fila = valores[i];
    if(fila[NUM_COLUMNA_BUSQUEDA] == valor) {
      var INT_R = i+1
      
      var valores1 = [[formulario.getRange("C3").getValue(),
                      formulario.getRange("C4").getValue(),
                      formulario.getRange("C5").getValue(),
                      formulario.getRange("C6").getValue(),
                      formulario.getRange("C7").getValue(),
                      formulario.getRange("C8").getValue()]];
      
      datos.getRange(INT_R, 1, 1, 6).setValues(valores1);
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Datos actualizados');

      Limpiar(); // Ejecución de función para limpieza de celdas
    }
  }
}

// Eliminar
function Eliminar() {
  var hojaActiva = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formulario = hojaActiva.getSheetByName("Ingreso Personal"); // Nombre de hoja del formulario
  var hojaDestino = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1CuP5yRxKrhubZbkb9KrTSJFn5OqyTPzbDi2ixKwJEpY')
  var datos = hojaDestino.getSheetByName("F09-Personal"); // Nombre de hoja donde se almacenan datos
  
  var interface = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var respuesta = interface.alert('¿Está seguro de borrar?',interface.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  
  // Proceso si el usuario responde
  if (respuesta == interface.Button.YES) {
    
    var valor = formulario.getRange("C11").getValue();
    var valores = hojaDestino.getSheetByName("F09-Personal").getDataRange().getValues(); // Nombre de hoja donde se almacenan datos
    for (var i = 0; i< valores.length; i++) {
      var fila = valores[i];
      if (fila[NUM_COLUMNA_BUSQUEDA] == valor) {
        var INT_R = i+1
        
        datos.deleteRow(INT_R);
        Limpiar(); // Ejecución de función para limpieza de celdas
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Our problem arises with the issue of permissions. The idea is that some of the colleagues can use the data entry forms to enter the information, but that they cannot access the file that works as a database. We originally thought that denying permission to view and edit the database templates would resolve this issue, but when those not authorized to view the database want to use the data entry templates, the following error appears:

> You do not have permission to access the requested document

The question is if there is any way to allow the use of the data entry forms, without giving access to the database ones.

Comment: You could send it so a temp database where everyone has permissions on and you pull in the data from a script bound to the database spreadsheet and clear the temp database. You can set this on a 30 min trigger for instance

Comment: It's not necessary to add the original code, actually the best is to add a [mcve]. When adding code you should describe how it works. If that is explained using inline comments that is fine but those comments should be in English. Before posting a question you should spend some time searching for helpful content from this site and if you still need help, the question should include a brief description of the most relevant posts, explaining why didn't help you or what was not clear.